# How do I properly create new files and apply multiple lines of input to it?

Tags: python, file-writing

I am trying to create 3 different files that I am then attempting to print ten random letters to print out 3 times in the file. 
Here is my code:

```
import string
import random

for i in range(3):
    with open('data%i.txt' % i, 'w+') as f:
        line = 0
        while line < 3:
            for j in range(10):
                myStr = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                f.write(myStr)

            line = line + 1
```

and output:

```
dfzanwalkccdipukrbwsrzrbheceqi
```

I've tried to print them with including the newline character in the file write, but that instead prints 30 lines with a single letter per line. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the newline in the line loop, not the character loop.

You can also change `while line < 3:` to `for line in range(3):`

```
for i in range(3):
    with open('data%i.txt' % i, 'w+') as f:
        for line in range(3):
            for j in range(10):
                myStr = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                f.write(myStr)
            f.write("\n")
```

You can also use `random.choices()` to get 10 random characters at once, instead of looping.

```
for i in range(3):
    with open('data%i.txt' % i, 'w+') as f:
        for line in range(3):
            myStr = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=10))
            f.write(myStr + "\n")
```